# Можно ли считать HTML+CSS ООП?

Tags: ооп

Собственно вопрос в теме, добавлю скажем

- `<div>`, `<p>`, `<img>` и т. д. - объекты
- `#id`, `.class`, свойства CSS - надстройки
- `:hover`, `:active`, `:focus` - события

(Не говорю про js)

Ну и вообще можно ли считать программированием или это разметка гипертекста, если так то как же конструкции типа:

```
CSS

.block {
display: none;
}

.target:hover ~ .block {
display: block;
{
```

Comment: НЕ смейте!

Comment: А что (+1), неожиданный, я бы сказал, интересный взгляд на программирование.

Я понимаю, что 99% будет спорить, но в принципе, язык разметки это ведь тоже язык программирования, только статический, задающий детерминированную программу, например, браузера.

Но, вот ООП? - это вряд ли.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Извините, но это очень странное допущение. 
Пройдем по порядку. Не буду останавливаться на том, что ни HTML ни CSS не являются языками программирования. Ключевой сущностью в ООП является класс, представляющий собой модель некой сущности. Класс обычно помимо состояния (то есть данных, описывающих саму сущность) включает в себя и модель поведения этой сущности (это достигается наличием у класса методов, или функций класса). Так вот в случае, о котором вы говорите, модель поведения отсутствует. 
Далее. Как известно, основными составляющими ООП являются наследование, полиморфизм и инкапсуляция. Я с трудом себе представляю, какие механизмы в случае с HTML+CSS можно  подогнать под эти три определения.Если наследование в рамках CSS еще может иметь какой-то смысл, то что понимать под полиморфизмом и инкапсуляцией?
Более того, то, что вы указали в качестве якобы относящегося к ООП, к нему имеют весьма слабое отношение (за исключением такого понятия как "объект", который вы, очевидно, путаете с классом). События конкретно к ООП отношения не имеют. Свойства напрямую с ООП тоже не связаны (более того, есть ощущение, что вы путаете свойства и поля), а что более важно, не являются для самой парадигмы ООП сколько-нибудь определяющими. А вот что такое "надстройки" в контексте ООП, вообще непонятно.

C другой стороны, с помощью [некоторых ухищрений](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665740/css-polymorphism-used-in-css3) можно добиться некоего подобия, но это будет больше похоже на [попытку превратить собаку в человека](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%8C%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B5), нежели на собственно ООП (необходимость которого в HTML+CSS очень сомнительна)

Comment: @Олег Б извините, но это очень всё притянуто за уши. Но что еще более важно - это не имеет особого смысла. Выглядит всего лишь как ненужная попытка запихнуть модное ООП в знакомый HTML

Comment: Да нет же, я не пишу резюме и тд) Работал с документом который был сверстан таблицой и все стили указывались что то вроде <table width="100%" height="100%" background-color="#000"> и у меня создался эффект что работаю "процедурно". А далее документ который сверстан div стало казаться будто работаешь с объектами особенно при position: absolute когда он индивидуален и не влияет на другие вот и спросил, отткуда столько неависти и минусов???

Comment: @Олег Б я минусы ставлю довольно часто, но конкретно этот я не минусовал, так что без понятия, откуда

Answer (score 4):

Если сильно захотеть, то html можно притянуть к ООП.  Объекты есть, полиморфизм и наследование есть (p и div могут вести себя похоже, имеют много одинаковых методов).

Но третья буква в ООП - программирование. А HTML - это язык разметки. Не программирования. В html5 уже есть js на борту, а там с ООП все более-менее.

Но зачем это все? если просто хочется вебмастеру добавить себе ООП в CV:) Тогда и водитель может себе это добавить. Ведь машины - это объекты. Наследование есть (различные модификации машин. Более того, в большинстве случаев предка даже явно указывают). Есть свойства у машин (кол-во колес, кол-во поршней). Полиморфизм? да пожалуйста. Если умеешь управлять одной машиной, то скорее всего сможешь управлять и целым семейством. Инкапсуляция? да, кто же крутит колеса монтировкой? только рулем, только круглым (некоторые цепляют квадратный руль, но это не мейнстрим).

Но все это не дает водителю машины говорить, что он использует и знает ООП.

Comment: Для личного самосовмещения, узнать мнение других, и более глубоко понять ООП. Не более того. Интересно почему минусуют вопрос?

Comment: потому что многие знают, что html - это не язык программирования, а ООП - это из программирования.

Comment: Связка html+css не язык программирования? Слайдеры написанные на чистом html+css3 или скажем многоуровневое меню на чистом css_html, вы не считаете что логика элементов имеет отношение к программированию?

Comment: гуглите про полноту по Тьюрингу

Comment: если html расшифровывается как  HyperText Markup Language — «язык разметки гипертекста», то что ещё говорить?